# How to bind nested property in label

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, label, nested-attributes

I want to bind an object property to a label. However I cannot get the binding to work properly. The object that I am binding is from a weather API.

code:

```
public seald class CurrentWeatherRepsonse: WeatherItem
{
    Temperature { Value {get; set;} } 
}

public CurrentWeatherResponse WeatherDataUi
        {
            get { return _weatherData; }
            set
            {
                _weatherData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

    //OnPropertyChanged Event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

xaml:

```
 <Label Grid.Row="2" DataContext="{ Binding WeatherDataUi}" Content="{Binding Temperature.Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="50"></Label>
```

Please note that I am binding form a **metadata** object.

Comment: check Output window in Visual Studio. if there are any binding errors you will see them. `Temperature { Value {get; set} }` is not valid c# syntax, what is it supposed to mean?

Comment: It was meant to show the the structure of my DataContext object.

Comment: Can you edit the code you have posted to be at least something that compiles.  Particularly let us know the type of Temperature, and its accessibility

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'WeatherDataUi' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindow' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=WeatherDataUi; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'Label' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object') this is my error in output file.

Comment: it seems that WeatherDataUi is not a property of the MainWindow class.

Comment: True is from another class WeatherObserver; that I initialize in the main: public MainWindow()  {  InitializeComponent(); weatherSubject = new WeatherSubject(); weatherObserver = new WeatherObserver(weatherSubject); DataContext=this; } How to gibe it the right path than?

Comment: set DataContext = weatherObserver

Comment: WeatherDataUi.Temperature.Value ---> this should work shouldn't it ?

Comment: I thought so too but I get a path error.

Comment: @Versatile it works when I set the binding to weatherObserver, but now I need something from different object weatherAlertObserver. Can I set the DataContext in such a way that both of them will bind correctly?

Comment: @GeorgianaM can you accept the answer as it resolved your problem ?

Comment: @GeorgianaM There should be a tick mark below the answer. You would want to select that.

Answer (score 1):

Check what is your data context. As already discussed for given problem your data context should be `weatherObserver` object as your properties are declared under that.
Sharing one view with different objects as data context will work only if you have the same property names at same levels. Though this is not recommended.

Also you can't have multiple objects in the data context at the same time.

Though approach to refer multiple objects for same view at the can be done somewhat like this:
Create a proxy object in your xaml

```
xmlns:proxy="Your namespace ;assembly=your assembly"

<proxy:BindingProxy x:Key="Proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
```

Use this to access other source for binding a property from different object

```
{Binding Data.DifferentProperty, Source={StaticResource Proxy}
```

Now even if the Labels data context is different this binding will refer to Procy object instance and get the Binding details from there.

Hopefully this answers your question !